# How to Keep Original Column Names with Sequel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel, tiny-tds

I have database with upper camelCase naming conventions eg. `MyColumn`. When using the [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) gem in my rails app to access the database the column is renamed to `mycolumn` as a model variable name or hash key. How can I preserve the original database column names in my code?

I am using a SQL Server DB with tiny-tds adapter. I am also using the sequel-rails gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the default mangling on MSSQL by using the identifier_mangling extension:

```
DB.extension(:identifier_mangling)
DB.identifier_input_method = DB.identifier_output_method = nil
```

Comment: didn't know this extension existed. I wrote my own thing that downcased and underscored all column names so that I'd have ruby style names.